# ref fields assignment rules in ref structs

Tags: c#, struct, ref

After a couple of hours of googling I still can't find an answer. Everyone just skips that bit.

So I have a ref struct like that

```cs
ref struct RefStruct
{
    public ref int X;
}
```

And I try to use it like that

```cs
void f()
{
    var x = 100;
    var s = new RefStruct();
    s.X = ref x;
}
```

That gives me a compiler error: Cannot ref-assign 'ref x' to 's.X' because 'ref x' has a narrower escape scope than 's.X'

What does that even mean? They're both in the same scope.

Let's add a counstructor

```cs
ref struct RefStruct
{
    public ref int X;
    
    public RefStruct(ref int x)
    {
        X = ref x;
    }
}

void f()
{
    var x = 100;
    var s = new RefStruct(ref x);
    s.X = ref x;
}
```

Now it's absolutely fine, `s` has narrower scope... But what changed? How `x`'s scope was extended?

Things may be even more strange

```cs
void f()
{
    var x = 100;
    var y = 5;
    var s = new RefStruct(ref y);
    s.X = ref x;
}
```

This one also works.

I really don't understand why I have to initialize the `ref` field via constructor until I'll be able to reassign it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [language proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements) which introduced `ref` fields.

The default "escape scope" of a local variable is based on how it was initialised. The exact semantics are a little weird, and designed around the semantics that were introduced in C#10 to support returning an instance of `Span<T>`.

```cs
// safe-to-escape == calling method
Span<int> x = default;
return x; // ok

// safe-to-escape == current method
Span<int> y = stackalloc int[42];
return y; // error
```

From your example, even though you aren't returning any of your `ref struct` variables. The compiler is enforcing "escape scope" rules as if you will return them.

```cs
// safe-to-escape == calling method, can be returned
var s = new RefStruct();
// safe-to-escape == current method, can't be returned
var s = new RefStruct(ref x);
```

When you attempt to assign `s.X = ref x`. The left hand side will have the "escape scope" of the variable above, but `ref x` will have a scope of "current method".

The CS8374 error will be raised if you try to assign a "current method" scope to a "calling method" scope.

But you can override the default escape scope definition by adding an explicit `scoped` modifier to you struct variable;

```cs
// safe-to-escape == current method
scoped var s = new RefStruct();
```

At the time of writing, there is a C# compiler [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/63797) to improve the CS8374 error message to suggest the use of the `scoped` modifier on the related local variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot ref-assign 'ref x' to 's.X' because 'ref x' has a narrower escape scope than 's.X'

What you should understand here is, `s` has a wider scope since it's `var` instead of `ref var`.

It is obvious why `ref x` has a narrower scope than `var s`, it's a local variable, `s` may outlive `x`.

And the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct#ref-fields) says:

> The compiler ensures that a reference stored in a ref field doesn't outlive its referent.

Basically, the last snippet you've posted is heuristically valid for the compiler.

Why initializing in constructor then assigning works? It's because the storage of `X` gets initialized.

Try debug this example that compiles to understand, it will NRE at runtime:

```
var x = 100;
var s = new RefStruct();
s.X = x; // no 'ref' keyword here
```